# extract a list of values from a variable, based on a list of indices, in R

Tags: r, indexing

I have a list of row indices for an R dataframe (dat). What function can I use to extract the corresponding values for a target variable (dat$id)?

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=c("s1","s2","s2","s3","s4","s4"), 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  visit=1:2,
                  age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE))
#dat
# id       date visit age
# 1 s1 2020-12-26     1  18
# 2 s2 2020-12-27     2  22
# 3 s2 2020-12-28     1  18
# 4 s3 2020-12-29     2  26
# 5 s4 2020-12-30     1  27
# 6 s4 2020-12-31     2  21

listindex->c(2,4,6)
#target variable is dat$id

desired_output:
s2
s3
s4
```

Comment: `dat$id[listindex]`

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[]` to subset the `id` values by row index.

```
dat$id[listindex]
#[1] "s2" "s3" "s4"
```